# What's the difference and impact of having CN defined in issuer and subject of x509 certificate?

Tags: openssl

Was going through this and was wondering if the value we place in CN of the issuer field and subject field are one and the same? Can someone please shed more lights on this?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Issuer is the entity that provides the cert and the Subject is the entity identified by the cert. The Issuer CN will be the name of the Trusted Authority that issues the certificate and the Subject CN will be your name, the name of your website, etc. Unless you are creating your own self-signed cert, in that case Issuer and Subject could be the same.